# XSLT converting question

Tags: html, xml, xslt, ms-office

I have some Microsoft Office Word file, saved as Office XML format output. I am wondering whether there are any XSLT samples which could convert Office XML format output into HTML format? Any other solutions (besides using XSLT) which could convert Office XML format output into HTML format is acceptable.

thanks in advance,
George

Comment: You have missed a recent SO XSLT question which is an excellent starting point. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297606/convert-ooxml-inline-formatting-to-a-merged-element/)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your collection of files is not large, then the easiest way to convert to HTML is to use Microsoft Word's save as HTML feature.  If the goal is to produce HTML output, regardless of the cleanliness of the output, that's the way to go.

You can also use a recorded macro to get MS Word to convert large numbers of files.

Edit: Answering comments

I mean use Microsoft Word to open the file (using File, Open), then using File, Save As and choosing "Web Page" as the type.  As for the macro, you can use [this Microsoft reference for macros](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/record-or-run-a-macro-HA010099769.aspx).

Comment: "the easiest way to convert to HTML is to use Microsoft Word's save as HTML feature" -- you mean save original word into html or saveing xml into html?

Comment: "You can also use a recorded macro to get MS Word to convert large numbers of files." --  Interesting, but never did this before. Could you show me some related documents for newcomer?