# Editing a PowerPoint slide with XSLT and change the value of an attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, powerpoint, xslt-1.0

I would like to be able to [group tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76789267/create-groupable-tables-in-powerpoint-with-vba) in PowerPoint, which is something [possible](https://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2016/09/xml-hacking-locking-graphics/) by editing the .xml files of slides. I am trying to change the value of

`<a:graphicFrameLocks noGrp="1"/>` (here in `Table 1`) from `1` to `0` everywhere. So every time it is run, the final result has `<a:graphicFrameLocks noGrp="0"/>` everywhere instead of `<a:graphicFrameLocks noGrp="1"/>`.

This means that I want to transform this file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<p:sld xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:p="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main">
    <p:cSld>
        <p:spTree>
            <p:nvGrpSpPr>
                <p:cNvPr id="1" name=""/>
                <p:cNvGrpSpPr/>
                <p:nvPr/>
            </p:nvGrpSpPr>
            <p:grpSpPr>
                <a:xfrm>
                    <a:off x="0" y="0"/>
                    <a:ext cx="0" cy="0"/>
                    <a:chOff x="0" y="0"/>
                    <a:chExt cx="0" cy="0"/>
                </a:xfrm>
            </p:grpSpPr>
            <p:graphicFrame>
                <p:nvGraphicFramePr>
                    <p:cNvPr id="2" name="Table 2">
                        <a:extLst>
                            <a:ext uri="{FF2B5EF4-FFF2-40B4-BE49-F238E27FC236}">
                                <a16:creationId xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main" id="{A3412BCC-6021-5BBE-8391-7BA6964B02B8}"/>
                            </a:ext>
                        </a:extLst>
                    </p:cNvPr>
                    <p:cNvGraphicFramePr>
                        <a:graphicFrameLocks noGrp="1"/>
                    </p:cNvGraphicFramePr>
                    <p:nvPr>
                        <p:extLst>
                            <p:ext uri="{D42A27DB-BD31-4B8C-83A1-F6EECF244321}">
                                <p14:modId xmlns:p14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/powerpoint/2010/main" val="2165210174"/>
                            </p:ext>
                        </p:extLst>
                    </p:nvPr>
                </p:nvGraphicFramePr>
                <p:xfrm>
                    <a:off x="2434021" y="4345735"/>
                    <a:ext cx="4064000" cy="370840"/>
                </p:xfrm>
                <a:graphic>
                    <a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/table">
                        <a:tbl>
                            <a:tblPr firstRow="1" bandRow="1">
                                <a:tableStyleId>{5C22544A-7EE6-4342-B048-85BDC9FD1C3A}</a:tableStyleId>
                            </a:tblPr>
                            <a:tblGrid>
                                <a:gridCol w="4064000">
                                    <a:extLst>
                                        <a:ext uri="{9D8B030D-6E8A-4147-A177-3AD203B41FA5}">
                                            <a16:colId xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main" val="310984077"/>
                                        </a:ext>
                                    </a:extLst>
                                </a:gridCol>
                            </a:tblGrid>
                            <a:tr h="370840">
                                <a:tc>
                                    <a:txBody>
                                        <a:bodyPr/>
                                        <a:lstStyle/>
                                        <a:p>
                                            <a:r>
                                                <a:rPr lang="en-US" dirty="0"/>
                                                <a:t>NORMAL</a:t>
                                            </a:r>
                                        </a:p>
                                    </a:txBody>
                                    <a:tcPr/>
                                </a:tc>
                                <a:extLst>
                                    <a:ext uri="{0D108BD9-81ED-4DB2-BD59-A6C34878D82A}">
                                        <a16:rowId xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main" val="1744877891"/>
                                    </a:ext>
                                </a:extLst>
                            </a:tr>
                        </a:tbl>
                    </a:graphicData>
                </a:graphic>
            </p:graphicFrame>
            <p:graphicFrame>
                <p:nvGraphicFramePr>
                    <p:cNvPr id="3" name="Table 2">
                        <a:extLst>
                            <a:ext uri="{FF2B5EF4-FFF2-40B4-BE49-F238E27FC236}">
                                <a16:creationId xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main" id="{3C111815-3269-B8CE-F6AA-E05EA0D31543}"/>
                            </a:ext>
                        </a:extLst>
                    </p:cNvPr>
                    <p:cNvGraphicFramePr>
                        <a:graphicFrameLocks noGrp="0"/>
                    </p:cNvGraphicFramePr>
                    <p:nvPr>
                        <p:extLst>
                            <p:ext uri="{D42A27DB-BD31-4B8C-83A1-F6EECF244321}">
                                <p14:modId xmlns:p14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/powerpoint/2010/main" val="205468608"/>
                            </p:ext>
                        </p:extLst>
                    </p:nvPr>
                </p:nvGraphicFramePr>
                <p:xfrm>
                    <a:off x="2434021" y="5075929"/>
                    <a:ext cx="4064000" cy="370840"/>
                </p:xfrm>
                <a:graphic>
                    <a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/table">
                        <a:tbl>
                            <a:tblPr firstRow="1" bandRow="1">
                                <a:tableStyleId>{5C22544A-7EE6-4342-B048-85BDC9FD1C3A}</a:tableStyleId>
                            </a:tblPr>
                            <a:tblGrid>
                                <a:gridCol w="4064000">
                                    <a:extLst>
                                        <a:ext uri="{9D8B030D-6E8A-4147-A177-3AD203B41FA5}">
                                            <a16:colId xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main" val="310984077"/>
                                        </a:ext>
                                    </a:extLst>
                                </a:gridCol>
                            </a:tblGrid>
                            <a:tr h="370840">
                                <a:tc>
                                    <a:txBody>
                                        <a:bodyPr/>
                                        <a:lstStyle/>
                                        <a:p>
                                            <a:r>
                                                <a:rPr lang="en-US" dirty="0"/>
                                                <a:t>GROUPABLE</a:t>
                                            </a:r>
                                        </a:p>
                                    </a:txBody>
                                    <a:tcPr/>
                                </a:tc>
                                <a:extLst>
                                    <a:ext uri="{0D108BD9-81ED-4DB2-BD59-A6C34878D82A}">
                                        <a16:rowId xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main" val="1744877891"/>
                                    </a:ext>
                                </a:extLst>
                            </a:tr>
                        </a:tbl>
                    </a:graphicData>
                </a:graphic>
            </p:graphicFrame>
        </p:spTree>
        <p:extLst>
            <p:ext uri="{BB962C8B-B14F-4D97-AF65-F5344CB8AC3E}">
                <p14:creationId xmlns:p14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/powerpoint/2010/main" val="851650981"/>
            </p:ext>
        </p:extLst>
    </p:cSld>
    <p:clrMapOvr>
        <a:masterClrMapping/>
    </p:clrMapOvr>
</p:sld>
```

into this file

The second table `Table 2` is groupable as intended i.e. `<a:graphicFrameLocks noGrp="0"/>`, but I made that manually and obviously I would like to automate this process.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<p:sld xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:p="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main">
    <p:cSld>
        <p:spTree>
            <p:nvGrpSpPr>
                <p:cNvPr id="1" name=""/>
                <p:cNvGrpSpPr/>
                <p:nvPr/>
            </p:nvGrpSpPr>
            <p:grpSpPr>
                <a:xfrm>
                    <a:off x="0" y="0"/>
                    <a:ext cx="0" cy="0"/>
                    <a:chOff x="0" y="0"/>
                    <a:chExt cx="0" cy="0"/>
                </a:xfrm>
            </p:grpSpPr>
            <p:graphicFrame>
                <p:nvGraphicFramePr>
                    <p:cNvPr id="2" name="Table 2">
                        <a:extLst>
                            <a:ext uri="{FF2B5EF4-FFF2-40B4-BE49-F238E27FC236}">
                                <a16:creationId xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main" id="{A3412BCC-6021-5BBE-8391-7BA6964B02B8}"/>
                            </a:ext>
                        </a:extLst>
                    </p:cNvPr>
                    <p:cNvGraphicFramePr>
                        <a:graphicFrameLocks noGrp="0"/>
                    </p:cNvGraphicFramePr>
                    <p:nvPr>
                        <p:extLst>
                            <p:ext uri="{D42A27DB-BD31-4B8C-83A1-F6EECF244321}">
                                <p14:modId xmlns:p14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/powerpoint/2010/main" val="2165210174"/>
                            </p:ext>
                        </p:extLst>
                    </p:nvPr>
                </p:nvGraphicFramePr>
                <p:xfrm>
                    <a:off x="2434021" y="4345735"/>
                    <a:ext cx="4064000" cy="370840"/>
                </p:xfrm>
                <a:graphic>
                    <a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/table">
                        <a:tbl>
                            <a:tblPr firstRow="1" bandRow="1">
                                <a:tableStyleId>{5C22544A-7EE6-4342-B048-85BDC9FD1C3A}</a:tableStyleId>
                            </a:tblPr>
                            <a:tblGrid>
                                <a:gridCol w="4064000">
                                    <a:extLst>
                                        <a:ext uri="{9D8B030D-6E8A-4147-A177-3AD203B41FA5}">
                                            <a16:colId xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main" val="310984077"/>
                                        </a:ext>
                                    </a:extLst>
                                </a:gridCol>
                            </a:tblGrid>
                            <a:tr h="370840">
                                <a:tc>
                                    <a:txBody>
                                        <a:bodyPr/>
                                        <a:lstStyle/>
                                        <a:p>
                                            <a:r>
                                                <a:rPr lang="en-US" dirty="0"/>
                                                <a:t>NORMAL</a:t>
                                            </a:r>
                                        </a:p>
                                    </a:txBody>
                                    <a:tcPr/>
                                </a:tc>
                                <a:extLst>
                                    <a:ext uri="{0D108BD9-81ED-4DB2-BD59-A6C34878D82A}">
                                        <a16:rowId xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main" val="1744877891"/>
                                    </a:ext>
                                </a:extLst>
                            </a:tr>
                        </a:tbl>
                    </a:graphicData>
                </a:graphic>
            </p:graphicFrame>
            <p:graphicFrame>
                <p:nvGraphicFramePr>
                    <p:cNvPr id="3" name="Table 2">
                        <a:extLst>
                            <a:ext uri="{FF2B5EF4-FFF2-40B4-BE49-F238E27FC236}">
                                <a16:creationId xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main" id="{3C111815-3269-B8CE-F6AA-E05EA0D31543}"/>
                            </a:ext>
                        </a:extLst>
                    </p:cNvPr>
                    <p:cNvGraphicFramePr>
                        <a:graphicFrameLocks noGrp="0"/>
                    </p:cNvGraphicFramePr>
                    <p:nvPr>
                        <p:extLst>
                            <p:ext uri="{D42A27DB-BD31-4B8C-83A1-F6EECF244321}">
                                <p14:modId xmlns:p14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/powerpoint/2010/main" val="205468608"/>
                            </p:ext>
                        </p:extLst>
                    </p:nvPr>
                </p:nvGraphicFramePr>
                <p:xfrm>
                    <a:off x="2434021" y="5075929"/>
                    <a:ext cx="4064000" cy="370840"/>
                </p:xfrm>
                <a:graphic>
                    <a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/table">
                        <a:tbl>
                            <a:tblPr firstRow="1" bandRow="1">
                                <a:tableStyleId>{5C22544A-7EE6-4342-B048-85BDC9FD1C3A}</a:tableStyleId>
                            </a:tblPr>
                            <a:tblGrid>
                                <a:gridCol w="4064000">
                                    <a:extLst>
                                        <a:ext uri="{9D8B030D-6E8A-4147-A177-3AD203B41FA5}">
                                            <a16:colId xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main" val="310984077"/>
                                        </a:ext>
                                    </a:extLst>
                                </a:gridCol>
                            </a:tblGrid>
                            <a:tr h="370840">
                                <a:tc>
                                    <a:txBody>
                                        <a:bodyPr/>
                                        <a:lstStyle/>
                                        <a:p>
                                            <a:r>
                                                <a:rPr lang="en-US" dirty="0"/>
                                                <a:t>GROUPABLE</a:t>
                                            </a:r>
                                        </a:p>
                                    </a:txBody>
                                    <a:tcPr/>
                                </a:tc>
                                <a:extLst>
                                    <a:ext uri="{0D108BD9-81ED-4DB2-BD59-A6C34878D82A}">
                                        <a16:rowId xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main" val="1744877891"/>
                                    </a:ext>
                                </a:extLst>
                            </a:tr>
                        </a:tbl>
                    </a:graphicData>
                </a:graphic>
            </p:graphicFrame>
        </p:spTree>
        <p:extLst>
            <p:ext uri="{BB962C8B-B14F-4D97-AF65-F5344CB8AC3E}">
                <p14:creationId xmlns:p14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/powerpoint/2010/main" val="851650981"/>
            </p:ext>
        </p:extLst>
    </p:cSld>
    <p:clrMapOvr>
        <a:masterClrMapping/>
    </p:clrMapOvr>
</p:sld>
```

**Update 1**

I added `<xsl:copy>` as I guess otherwise the code would have not given output.

**Update 2**

I tried also with this code, but I get error it is not well-formed.

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297606/convert-ooxml-inline-formatting-to-a-merged-element) question and [its](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6367044/18247317) answer, I made the below XSLT, that i ran by launching it from VBA (fixed one previous error with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38701367/18247317)) and I got:

`Error: a reference to variable or parameter 'noGrp' cannot be resolved. The variable or parameter may not be defined, or ir may not be in scope.`

I am not very practical with XSLT, the solution may be very simple.

**First XSLT I tried**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:safe="http://www.esa.int/safe/sentinel-1.0"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common" xmlns:p="p" xmlns:a="a"
 exclude-result-prefixes="ext p"  >

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:variable name="graphicFrameLocks" select="//p:sld/p:cSld
                [p:spTree[p:nvGrpSpPr[p:grpSpPr[p:graphicFrame[p:nvGraphicFramePr[p:cNvGraphicFramePr[@a:graphicFrameLocks='noGrp']]]]]]]"/>
    <xsl:variable name="noGrp">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$noGrp">
                <xsl:value-of select="1"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="0"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Second XSLT I tried**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="//a:graphicFrameLocks">
      <xsl:if test="@noGrp='1'">
        <xsl:attribute name="noGrp">0</xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Update 3**

I [was able to change the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76789267/create-groupable-tables-in-powerpoint-with-vba), but not through XSLT, so the issue is still open.

**Reformulation**
I would like to be able to group tables in PowerPoint, which is something [possible](https://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2016/09/xml-hacking-locking-graphics/) by editing the .xml files of slides. I am trying to change the value of the attribute `noGrp`

`<a:graphicFrameLocks noGrp="1"/>` (here in `Table 1`) from `1` to `0` everywhere. So every time it is run, the final result has `<a:graphicFrameLocks noGrp="0"/>` everywhere instead of `<a:graphicFrameLocks noGrp="1"/>` when **the element is a table** `<a:tbl>` (I think this is the reason the question looked not clear).

I understood I have to declare the namespaces I find in the .xml of the slide:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main"
 xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"
 xmlns:p="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main"
 exclude-result-prefixes="a r p">
```

and going on from there

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Hello michael, do you mean the last part (the full slide) is redundant? Or should I actually also add the VBA code to run the XSLT?

Comment: We should see a minimal, but still complete example of the XML input. And the expected output. An explanation of the required logic would also useful. If your question is about XSLT, then the VBA code is irrelevant.

Comment: There is all this information: **XSLT** is the transformation file, **Full file** the input file, the output file is the same of the input file, with the line `<a:graphicFrameLocks noGrp="1"/>` transformed into `<a:graphicFrameLocks noGrp="0"/>` as said in the question. Could you please clarify what is missing?

Comment: You ignored everything I said.

Comment: No, I really don't understand what is missing. There is the .xml file to transform, the logic behind, the XSLT file, the result. I mentioned the VBA but without code, I linked all the sources I could relate to the question and I do not understand what more I should provide.

Comment: I rewrote the question, could you please let me know if it is still missing something, and what?

Comment: Try following the approach outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72913583/16462950).

Comment: thank you, exactly the bits I need to get the understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the tree of the main part of interest:

```
<p:sld xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:p="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main">
    <p:cSld>
        <p:spTree>
            <p:nvGrpSpPr>
                <p:cNvPr id="1" name="">
                </p:cNvPr>
                <p:cNvGrpSpPr>
                </p:cNvGrpSpPr>
                <p:nvPr>
                </p:nvPr>
            </p:nvGrpSpPr>
            <p:grpSpPr>
                <a:xfrm>
                    <a:off x="0" y="0">
                    </a:off>
                    <a:ext cx="0" cy="0">
                    </a:ext>
                    <a:chOff x="0" y="0">
                    </a:chOff>
                    <a:chExt cx="0" cy="0">
                    </a:chExt>
                </a:xfrm>
            </p:grpSpPr>
            <p:graphicFrame>
                <p:nvGraphicFramePr>
                    <p:cNvPr id="2" name="Table 2">
                        <a:extLst>
                            <a:ext uri="{FF2B5EF4-FFF2-40B4-BE49-F238E27FC236}">
                                <a16:creationId id="{A28AB9B7-FB4F-FF3F-2403-3A4F483AC390}" xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main">
                                </a16:creationId>
                            </a:ext>
                        </a:extLst>
                    </p:cNvPr>
                    <p:cNvGraphicFramePr>
                        <a:graphicFrameLocks noGrp="1">
                        </a:graphicFrameLocks>
                    </p:cNvGraphicFramePr>
                    <p:nvPr>
                    </p:nvPr>
                </p:nvGraphicFramePr>
                <p:xfrm>
                    <a:off x="2032000" y="719666">
                    </a:off>
                    <a:ext cx="8127999" cy="370840">
                    </a:ext>
                </p:xfrm>
                <a:graphic>
                    <a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/table">
                        <a:tbl> <!-- Here I get to see if it's a table -->
```

To find out if the shape is a table the relevant part is in `<p:graphicFrame>` , at  `<a:tbl>`:

```
<p:graphicFrame>
 <p:nvGraphicFramePr>
  <a:graphic>
   <a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/table">
    <a:tbl>
```

1. After placing the correct [namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20680122/18247317)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main"
 xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"
 xmlns:p="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main"
 exclude-result-prefixes="a r p">
```

2. I had to add this to avoid the characters not being recognized properly and to avoid leaving the declarations, thus rendering the file very likely unusable in PowerPoint (the output was in Chinese characters, I actually didn't even try turning it back to slide):

```
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

3. Then, match the full original xml file:

```
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

4. and search through the above path (`<p:graphicFrame>` >> `<p:nvGraphicFramePr><a:graphic>` >> `<a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/table">` >> `<a:tbl>`) to know if the shapes are tables, and from there, take all the content of `nvGraphicFramePr` (because it's the closest common parent they have) and select the part of interest with `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|p:nvGraphicFramePr/p:cNvGraphicFramePr/a:graphicFrameLocks"/>` this will be sent to the actual transformation in the next step

```
  <xsl:template match="a:graphicFrame[a:graphic/a:graphicData[@uri='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/table']/a:tbl]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|p:nvGraphicFramePr/p:cNvGraphicFramePr/a:graphicFrameLocks"/>       
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

5. that is, change_values_of/add [attibutes](http://www.datypic.com/sc/ooxml/s-dml-documentProperties.xsd.html) and close the transformation file

`noRot="0"` is useless, I was dreaming of tables that could also be rotated, not only grouped, but it won't work. The output file will not be negatively affected, once opened PowerPoint will complain and fix it alone (I have not checked if that bit is deleted, but the slide was nonetheless working. The line can just be removed).

```
  <xsl:template match="a:graphicFrameLocks">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:attribute name="noGrp">0</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="noRot">0</xsl:attribute>   <!-- More interesting are noMov noResize, NoUngrp, noRot does not work for tables -->
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

this is the wanted **output**

```
<p:sld xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:p="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main">
    <p:cSld>
        <p:spTree>
            <p:nvGrpSpPr>
                <p:cNvPr id="1" name="">
                </p:cNvPr>
                <p:cNvGrpSpPr>
                </p:cNvGrpSpPr>
                <p:nvPr>
                </p:nvPr>
            </p:nvGrpSpPr>
            <p:grpSpPr>
                <a:xfrm>
                    <a:off x="0" y="0">
                    </a:off>
                    <a:ext cx="0" cy="0">
                    </a:ext>
                    <a:chOff x="0" y="0">
                    </a:chOff>
                    <a:chExt cx="0" cy="0">
                    </a:chExt>
                </a:xfrm>
            </p:grpSpPr>
            <p:graphicFrame>
                <p:nvGraphicFramePr>
                    <p:cNvPr id="4" name="Table 4">
                        <a:extLst>
                            <a:ext uri="{FF2B5EF4-FFF2-40B4-BE49-F238E27FC236}">
                                <a16:creationId id="{62C2F72A-961E-38CD-579B-5D3EE41AD59D}" xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main">
                                </a16:creationId>
                            </a:ext>
                        </a:extLst>
                    </p:cNvPr>
                    <p:cNvGraphicFramePr>
                        <a:graphicFrameLocks noGrp="0" noRot="0"/>
                    </p:cNvGraphicFramePr>
                    <p:nvPr>
                        <p:extLst>
                            <p:ext uri="{D42A27DB-BD31-4B8C-83A1-F6EECF244321}">
                                <p14:modId val="2104916695" xmlns:p14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/powerpoint/2010/main">
                                </p14:modId>
                            </p:ext>
                        </p:extLst>
                    </p:nvPr>
                </p:nvGraphicFramePr>
                <p:xfrm>
                    <a:off x="2032000" y="719666">
                    </a:off>
                    <a:ext cx="8128000" cy="1112520">
                    </a:ext>
                </p:xfrm>
                <a:graphic>
                    <a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/table">
                        <a:tbl>
                            <a:tblPr firstRow="1" bandRow="1">
                                <a:tableStyleId>{5C22544A-7EE6-4342-B048-85BDC9FD1C3A}</a:tableStyleId>
                            </a:tblPr>
                            <a:tblGrid>
                                <a:gridCol w="2032000">
                                    <a:extLst>
                                        <a:ext uri="{9D8B030D-6E8A-4147-A177-3AD203B41FA5}">
                                            <a16:colId val="3808446617" xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main">
                                            </a16:colId>
                                        </a:ext>
                                    </a:extLst>
                                </a:gridCol>
                                <a:gridCol w="2032000">
                                    <a:extLst>
                                        <a:ext uri="{9D8B030D-6E8A-4147-A177-3AD203B41FA5}">
                                            <a16:colId val="2100669385" xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main">
                                            </a16:colId>
                                        </a:ext>
                                    </a:extLst>
                                </a:gridCol>
                                <a:gridCol w="2032000">
                                    <a:extLst>
                                        <a:ext uri="{9D8B030D-6E8A-4147-A177-3AD203B41FA5}">
                                            <a16:colId val="2896383776" xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main">
                                            </a16:colId>
                                        </a:ext>
                                    </a:extLst>
                                </a:gridCol>
                                <a:gridCol w="2032000">
                                    <a:extLst>
                                        <a:ext uri="{9D8B030D-6E8A-4147-A177-3AD203B41FA5}">
                                            <a16:colId val="1582439423" xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main">
                                            </a16:colId>
                                        </a:ext>
                                    </a:extLst>
                                </a:gridCol>
                            </a:tblGrid>
                            <a:tr h="370840">
                                <a:tc>
                                    <a:txBody>
                                        <a:bodyPr>
                                        </a:bodyPr>
                                        <a:lstStyle>
                                        </a:lstStyle>
                                        <a:p>
                                            <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" dirty="0">
                                            </a:endParaRPr>
                                        </a:p>
                                    </a:txBody>
                                    <a:tcPr>
                                    </a:tcPr>
                                </a:tc>
                                <a:tc>
                                    <a:txBody>
                                        <a:bodyPr>
                                        </a:bodyPr>
                                        <a:lstStyle>
                                        </a:lstStyle>
                                        <a:p>
                                            <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US">
                                            </a:endParaRPr>
                                        </a:p>
                                    </a:txBody>
                                    <a:tcPr>
                                    </a:tcPr>
                                </a:tc>
                                <a:tc>
                                    <a:txBody>
                                        <a:bodyPr>
                                        </a:bodyPr>
                                        <a:lstStyle>
                                        </a:lstStyle>
                                        <a:p>
                                            <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US">
                                            </a:endParaRPr>
                                        </a:p>
                                    </a:txBody>
                                    <a:tcPr>
                                    </a:tcPr>
                                </a:tc>
                                <a:tc>
                                    <a:txBody>
                                        <a:bodyPr>
                                        </a:bodyPr>
                                        <a:lstStyle>
                                        </a:lstStyle>
                                        <a:p>
                                            <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US">
                                            </a:endParaRPr>
                                        </a:p>
                                    </a:txBody>
                                    <a:tcPr>
                                    </a:tcPr>
                                </a:tc>
                                <a:extLst>
                                    <a:ext uri="{0D108BD9-81ED-4DB2-BD59-A6C34878D82A}">
                                        <a16:rowId val="2591922936" xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main">
                                        </a16:rowId>
                                    </a:ext>
                                </a:extLst>
                            </a:tr>
                            <a:tr h="370840">
                                <a:tc>
                                    <a:txBody>
                                        <a:bodyPr>
                                        </a:bodyPr>
                                        <a:lstStyle>
                                        </a:lstStyle>
                                        <a:p>
                                            <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US">
                                            </a:endParaRPr>
                                        </a:p>
                                    </a:txBody>
                                    <a:tcPr>
                                    </a:tcPr>
                                </a:tc>
                                <a:tc>
                                    <a:txBody>
                                        <a:bodyPr>
                                        </a:bodyPr>
                                        <a:lstStyle>
                                        </a:lstStyle>
                                        <a:p>
                                            <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US">
                                            </a:endParaRPr>
                                        </a:p>
                                    </a:txBody>
                                    <a:tcPr>
                                    </a:tcPr>
                                </a:tc>
                                <a:tc>
                                    <a:txBody>
                                        <a:bodyPr>
                                        </a:bodyPr>
                                        <a:lstStyle>
                                        </a:lstStyle>
                                        <a:p>
                                            <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US">
                                            </a:endParaRPr>
                                        </a:p>
                                    </a:txBody>
                                    <a:tcPr>
                                    </a:tcPr>
                                </a:tc>
                                <a:tc>
                                    <a:txBody>
                                        <a:bodyPr>
                                        </a:bodyPr>
                                        <a:lstStyle>
                                        </a:lstStyle>
                                        <a:p>
                                            <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US">
                                            </a:endParaRPr>
                                        </a:p>
                                    </a:txBody>
                                    <a:tcPr>
                                    </a:tcPr>
                                </a:tc>
                                <a:extLst>
                                    <a:ext uri="{0D108BD9-81ED-4DB2-BD59-A6C34878D82A}">
                                        <a16:rowId val="2190715157" xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main">
                                        </a16:rowId>
                                    </a:ext>
                                </a:extLst>
                            </a:tr>
                            <a:tr h="370840">
                                <a:tc>
                                    <a:txBody>
                                        <a:bodyPr>
                                        </a:bodyPr>
                                        <a:lstStyle>
                                        </a:lstStyle>
                                        <a:p>
                                            <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US">
                                            </a:endParaRPr>
                                        </a:p>
                                    </a:txBody>
                                    <a:tcPr>
                                    </a:tcPr>
                                </a:tc>
                                <a:tc>
                                    <a:txBody>
                                        <a:bodyPr>
                                        </a:bodyPr>
                                        <a:lstStyle>
                                        </a:lstStyle>
                                        <a:p>
                                            <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US">
                                            </a:endParaRPr>
                                        </a:p>
                                    </a:txBody>
                                    <a:tcPr>
                                    </a:tcPr>
                                </a:tc>
                                <a:tc>
                                    <a:txBody>
                                        <a:bodyPr>
                                        </a:bodyPr>
                                        <a:lstStyle>
                                        </a:lstStyle>
                                        <a:p>
                                            <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US">
                                            </a:endParaRPr>
                                        </a:p>
                                    </a:txBody>
                                    <a:tcPr>
                                    </a:tcPr>
                                </a:tc>
                                <a:tc>
                                    <a:txBody>
                                        <a:bodyPr>
                                        </a:bodyPr>
                                        <a:lstStyle>
                                        </a:lstStyle>
                                        <a:p>
                                            <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" dirty="0">
                                            </a:endParaRPr>
                                        </a:p>
                                    </a:txBody>
                                    <a:tcPr>
                                    </a:tcPr>
                                </a:tc>
                                <a:extLst>
                                    <a:ext uri="{0D108BD9-81ED-4DB2-BD59-A6C34878D82A}">
                                        <a16:rowId val="921931565" xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main">
                                        </a16:rowId>
                                    </a:ext>
                                </a:extLst>
                            </a:tr>
                        </a:tbl>
                    </a:graphicData>
                </a:graphic>
            </p:graphicFrame>
            <p:graphicFrame>
                <p:nvGraphicFramePr>
                    <p:cNvPr id="5" name="Table 456">
                        <a:extLst>
                            <a:ext uri="{FF2B5EF4-FFF2-40B4-BE49-F238E27FC236}">
                                <a16:creationId id="{F32CD8FD-F9E5-EB18-DEA9-089E95A17EA3}" xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main">
                                </a16:creationId>
                            </a:ext>
                        </a:extLst>
                    </p:cNvPr>
                    <p:cNvGraphicFramePr>
                        <a:graphicFrameLocks noGrp="0" noRot="0"/>
                    </p:cNvGraphicFramePr>
                    <p:nvPr>
                        <p:extLst>
                            <p:ext uri="{D42A27DB-BD31-4B8C-83A1-F6EECF244321}">
                                <p14:modId val="2019305350" xmlns:p14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/powerpoint/2010/main">
                                </p14:modId>
                            </p:ext>
                        </p:extLst>
                    </p:nvPr>
                </p:nvGraphicFramePr>
                <p:xfrm>
                    <a:off x="2032000" y="2872740">
                    </a:off>
                    <a:ext cx="8128000" cy="1112520">
                    </a:ext>
                </p:xfrm>
                <a:graphic>
                    <a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/table">
                        <a:tbl>
                            <a:tblPr firstRow="1" bandRow="1">
                                <a:tableStyleId>{5C22544A-7EE6-4342-B048-85BDC9FD1C3A}</a:tableStyleId>
                            </a:tblPr>
                            <a:tblGrid>
                                <a:gridCol w="2032000">
                                    <a:extLst>
                                        <a:ext uri="{9D8B030D-6E8A-4147-A177-3AD203B41FA5}">
                                            <a16:colId val="3808446617" xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main">
                                            </a16:colId>
                                        </a:ext>
                                    </a:extLst>
                                </a:gridCol>
                                <a:gridCol w="2032000">
                                    <a:extLst>
                                        <a:ext uri="{9D8B030D-6E8A-4147-A177-3AD203B41FA5}">
                                            <a16:colId val="2100669385" xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main">
                                            </a16:colId>
                                        </a:ext>
                                    </a:extLst>
                                </a:gridCol>
                                <a:gridCol w="2032000">
                                    <a:extLst>
                                        <a:ext uri="{9D8B030D-6E8A-4147-A177-3AD203B41FA5}">
                                            <a16:colId val="2896383776" xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main">
                                            </a16:colId>
                                        </a:ext>
                                    </a:extLst>
                                </a:gridCol>
                                <a:gridCol w="2032000">
                                    <a:extLst>
                                        <a:ext uri="{9D8B030D-6E8A-4147-A177-3AD203B41FA5}">
                                            <a16:colId val="1582439423" xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main">
                                            </a16:colId>
                                        </a:ext>
                                    </a:extLst>
                                </a:gridCol>
                            </a:tblGrid>
                            <a:tr h="370840">
                                <a:tc>
                                    <a:txBody>
                                        <a:bodyPr>
                                        </a:bodyPr>
                                        <a:lstStyle>
                                        </a:lstStyle>
                                        <a:p>
                                            <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" dirty="0">
                                            </a:endParaRPr>
                                        </a:p>
                                    </a:txBody>
                                    <a:tcPr>
                                    </a:tcPr>
                                </a:tc>
                                <a:tc>
                                    <a:txBody>
                                        <a:bodyPr>
                                        </a:bodyPr>
                                        <a:lstStyle>
                                        </a:lstStyle>
                                        <a:p>
                                            <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US">
                                            </a:endParaRPr>
                                        </a:p>
                                    </a:txBody>
                                    <a:tcPr>
                                    </a:tcPr>
                                </a:tc>
                                <a:tc>
                                    <a:txBody>
                                        <a:bodyPr>
                                        </a:bodyPr>
                                        <a:lstStyle>
                                        </a:lstStyle>
                                        <a:p>
                                            <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US">
                                            </a:endParaRPr>
                                        </a:p>
                                    </a:txBody>
                                    <a:tcPr>
                                    </a:tcPr>
                                </a:tc>
                                <a:tc>
                                    <a:txBody>
                                        <a:bodyPr>
                                        </a:bodyPr>
                                        <a:lstStyle>
                                        </a:lstStyle>
                                        <a:p>
                                            <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US">
                                            </a:endParaRPr>
                                        </a:p>
                                    </a:txBody>
                                    <a:tcPr>
                                    </a:tcPr>
                                </a:tc>
                                <a:extLst>
                                    <a:ext uri="{0D108BD9-81ED-4DB2-BD59-A6C34878D82A}">
                                        <a16:rowId val="2591922936" xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main">
                                        </a16:rowId>
                                    </a:ext>
                                </a:extLst>
                            </a:tr>
                            <a:tr h="370840">
                                <a:tc>
                                    <a:txBody>
                                        <a:bodyPr>
                                        </a:bodyPr>
                                        <a:lstStyle>
                                        </a:lstStyle>
                                        <a:p>
                                            <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US">
                                            </a:endParaRPr>
                                        </a:p>
                                    </a:txBody>
                                    <a:tcPr>
                                    </a:tcPr>
                                </a:tc>
                                <a:tc>
                                    <a:txBody>
                                        <a:bodyPr>
                                        </a:bodyPr>
                                        <a:lstStyle>
                                        </a:lstStyle>
                                        <a:p>
                                            <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US">
                                            </a:endParaRPr>
                                        </a:p>
                                    </a:txBody>
                                    <a:tcPr>
                                    </a:tcPr>
                                </a:tc>
                                <a:tc>
                                    <a:txBody>
                                        <a:bodyPr>
                                        </a:bodyPr>
                                        <a:lstStyle>
                                        </a:lstStyle>
                                        <a:p>
                                            <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US">
                                            </a:endParaRPr>
                                        </a:p>
                                    </a:txBody>
                                    <a:tcPr>
                                    </a:tcPr>
                                </a:tc>
                                <a:tc>
                                    <a:txBody>
                                        <a:bodyPr>
                                        </a:bodyPr>
                                        <a:lstStyle>
                                        </a:lstStyle>
                                        <a:p>
                                            <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US">
                                            </a:endParaRPr>
                                        </a:p>
                                    </a:txBody>
                                    <a:tcPr>
                                    </a:tcPr>
                                </a:tc>
                                <a:extLst>
                                    <a:ext uri="{0D108BD9-81ED-4DB2-BD59-A6C34878D82A}">
                                        <a16:rowId val="2190715157" xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main">
                                        </a16:rowId>
                                    </a:ext>
                                </a:extLst>
                            </a:tr>
                            <a:tr h="370840">
                                <a:tc>
                                    <a:txBody>
                                        <a:bodyPr>
                                        </a:bodyPr>
                                        <a:lstStyle>
                                        </a:lstStyle>
                                        <a:p>
                                            <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US">
                                            </a:endParaRPr>
                                        </a:p>
                                    </a:txBody>
                                    <a:tcPr>
                                    </a:tcPr>
                                </a:tc>
                                <a:tc>
                                    <a:txBody>
                                        <a:bodyPr>
                                        </a:bodyPr>
                                        <a:lstStyle>
                                        </a:lstStyle>
                                        <a:p>
                                            <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US">
                                            </a:endParaRPr>
                                        </a:p>
                                    </a:txBody>
                                    <a:tcPr>
                                    </a:tcPr>
                                </a:tc>
                                <a:tc>
                                    <a:txBody>
                                        <a:bodyPr>
                                        </a:bodyPr>
                                        <a:lstStyle>
                                        </a:lstStyle>
                                        <a:p>
                                            <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US">
                                            </a:endParaRPr>
                                        </a:p>
                                    </a:txBody>
                                    <a:tcPr>
                                    </a:tcPr>
                                </a:tc>
                                <a:tc>
                                    <a:txBody>
                                        <a:bodyPr>
                                        </a:bodyPr>
                                        <a:lstStyle>
                                        </a:lstStyle>
                                        <a:p>
                                            <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" dirty="0">
                                            </a:endParaRPr>
                                        </a:p>
                                    </a:txBody>
                                    <a:tcPr>
                                    </a:tcPr>
                                </a:tc>
                                <a:extLst>
                                    <a:ext uri="{0D108BD9-81ED-4DB2-BD59-A6C34878D82A}">
                                        <a16:rowId val="921931565" xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main">
                                        </a16:rowId>
                                    </a:ext>
                                </a:extLst>
                            </a:tr>
                        </a:tbl>
                    </a:graphicData>
                </a:graphic>
            </p:graphicFrame>
        </p:spTree>
        <p:extLst>
            <p:ext uri="{BB962C8B-B14F-4D97-AF65-F5344CB8AC3E}">
                <p14:creationId val="4040289691" xmlns:p14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/powerpoint/2010/main">
                </p14:creationId>
            </p:ext>
        </p:extLst>
    </p:cSld>
    <p:clrMapOvr>
        <a:masterClrMapping>
        </a:masterClrMapping>
    </p:clrMapOvr>
</p:sld>
```

**Update**

I can actually stop earlier and find the namespace without bothering about the `<tbl>` element, but it can be useful to leave as it is so the path to the data within the table itself is already set.

```
  <xsl:template match="a:graphicFrame[a:graphic/a:graphicData/@uri='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/table']">
```